# Why does kafka-python consumer poll always return only one message? (timeout_ms behavior)

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm still confused by poll's timeout and max_record parameters. I setup timeout for a long period (like 30000ms), Here is the demo code:

```
msg_pack = consumer.poll(timeout_ms=30000, max_records=10)
print("polled", flush=True)
```

when a poll received any message, it process and return.

So does timeout only mean waiting for empty buffer? Then in which case it can fetch multiple messages and make max_records meaningful?

Comment: how many message did you send when testing?

Comment: When doing testing, I tried a few different cases, like producing 1,10 and at most 50 message one time and multiple time.